# MS Graph, Excel workbook: How can I determine which cells are merged within a range

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to use Microsoft Graph to read relevant information for financial tables stored in Excel documents on Sharepoint. The tables are stored either in a Range or in a Named range (using the "Define name" functionality in Excel).

I have been able to:

1. Get all cell values from the range, e.g: `sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/workbook/names/{named-range}/range`
2. Get all cells' formatting, including fill, font, text alignment and cell size, by querying each individual cell for its' format, e.g: `sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/workbook/worksheets/{sheet-name}/range(address='B2')/format?$expand=fill,font`

There are also `POST` endpoints to merge/unmerge cells. However, I can't find a way to deduce whether a cell has been merged or not?

**How can I determine which cells are merged within a range?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph API uses Excel API under the hood and Excel API itself doesn't have method to get merged cells.

I've tried to merge/unmerge range of cells and check what the endpoint `/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='<address>')` returns.

I've a range `A1:C3` of unmerged cells. When I call the endpoint

`/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='A1:C3')`

the response is:

```
{
    ...
    "address": "List2!A1:C3",
    "addressLocal": "List2!A1:C3",
    "columnCount": 3,
    "cellCount": 9,
    "columnHidden": false,
    "rowHidden": false,
    "columnIndex": 0,
    ...
    "hidden": false,
    "rowCount": 3,
    "rowIndex": 0,
    ...
}
```

When I merged cells `A1:C3` and called again the same endpoint

the result is similar to the previous one.

```
{
    ...
    "address": "List2!A1",
    "addressLocal": "List2!A1",
    "columnCount": 3,
    "cellCount": 9,
    "columnHidden": false,
    "rowHidden": false,    
    "columnIndex": 0,
    ...
    "hidden": false,
    "rowCount": 3,
    "rowIndex": 0,
    ...
}
```

Only difference is that for unmerged cells the `address` is `List2!A1:C3` and for merged cells is `List2!A1`.

So, if you have a specific range, you can only check if all cells within the specified range are merged by checking `address` property but you can get additional info like if some cells within the range are merged etc.

Comment: I might have been a little unclear. I don't want to merge/unmerge. I want to figure out which cells within the range are already merged. Ideally that info could've been available in the range response, but I'm also fine with querying per cell. If the information is somehow available..?

Comment: The way I understand it, `addressLocal` is just a localized version of the `address`. E.g. me being a Norwegian, the next letters after A-Z would be ÆØÅ. I don't think this is usable unfortunately.

Comment: I understand and I'm afraid that there is no API to get merged cells but check the updated answer.

Comment: To clarify - did you merge these cells directly in the workbook, or by using the merge/unmerge endpoints?

Edit: Nevermind - I was able to reproduce what you've done. Thank you. I am unfortunately not sure how to use this in a meaningful way - I shall have to think on it. :)

Comment: @AndreasO During testing I merged these cells directly in the workbook.

Comment: Thanks. Awarded the bounty - thank you for investigating. I would obviously have wished for a smoother solution, but have found that this "naive" check of merging can actually work in my use-case. But I am eagerly awaiting whenever MS decides to expose the information in a better way.